# Select parent rows based on several column combinations from a child table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given the following tables:

parent:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

property:

```
+----+-----------+------+-------+
| id | parent_id | name | value |
+----+-----------+------+-------+
|  1 |         1 | aaa  |     5 |
|  2 |         1 | bbb  |     2 |
|  3 |         1 | ccc  |     9 |
|  4 |         2 | aaa  |     8 |
|  5 |         2 | ccc  |     9 |
|  6 |         3 | bbb  |    10 |
|  7 |         3 | ddd  |     1 |
|  8 |         3 | ccc  |     9 |
+----+-----------+------+-------+
```

In general, queries are in the following form:
Select parent ids if:

```
* Have a property called 'xxx' with value 'yyy'                                         <---|
* and/or                                                                                    |
* Have a property called 'xxx' with value NOT equal 'yyy' OR do not have 'xxx' proprty. <---|
* and/or                                                                                    |
* Repeat -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

So for example, a query might look like this:
Select parent ids if:

- Have a property called 'bbb' and it's value != 2 OR do not have a 'bbb' property.
- (and)
- Have a property called 'ccc' and it's value == 9.

In the above example, the result of the query would be:

- 2 (doesn't have a 'bbb' property and has a 'ccc' == 9).
- 3 (Has a 'bbb' property with a value != 2 and has a 'ccc' == 9).

Currently, I am doing something like this:

```sql
select * from parent where
    -- use "not in" and invert check for "NOT equal or no property queries"
    id not in (select parent_id from property where name = 'bbb' and value = 2)
    and id in (select parent_id from property where name = 'ccc' and value = 9)
```

I was wondering if there is a better approach as this can grow to too many `select` inside the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the tables and use conditional aggregation:

```
select p.id
from parent p inner join property t
on t.parent_id = p.id
group by p.id
having sum(t.name = 'bbb' and t.value = 2) = 0
   and sum(t.name = 'ccc' and t.value = 9) > 0
```

This is not necessarily better performance-wise than your solution, but I think that it's more readable and better scalable so you can add more conditions.

There is also a solution with `EXISTS` / `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select p.* from parent p
where not exists (select 1 from  property t where t.parent_id = p.id and t.name = 'bbb' and t.value = 2)
  and exists (select 1 from  property t where t.parent_id = p.id and t.name = 'ccc' and t.value = 9)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=20f0e0a7848de78259d78d45c43e75e0).
Results:

```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Forpas' answer is corect.  However, it can be simplified and improved in two ways.

First, no `join` is needed for the query.  Second, SQLite supports tuple notation to simplify the logic.  So the logic can be expressed as:

```
select parent_id
from property p
group by parent_id
having sum( (name, value) = ('ccc', 9) ) > 0 and
       sum( (name, value) = ('bbb', 2) ) = 0;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fdc77/5) is a SQL Fiddle.